# CakePHP, MySQL query taking time which locks my UI

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a peculiar problem which has arisen in my application off late . In one of the pages , a sql query is taking too much time to load , and it is causing my UI to get locked . What happens is untill and unless that query gets completed in the backend, I can't see anything in the browser .

Also , if I open a new tab and hit the same url there, my browser won't show anything and will wait till my query finishes.

In the present scenario, I can't change the query immidiately , it needs time to optimize it, but till then I need some time-out settings wither in the mysql db or in cakephp, where in my UI won't wait for the query to finish.

How to do that?

Comment: How do you display a page without the data that it's supposed to display...?

Comment: You didn't get my point . If my query takes too long a time to execute , my page waits for the entire duration to get loaded , there is no point to wait till eternity , now if any user tries to close the current tab and open another page in a new tab , that page is getting locked too , I mean it also , as it seems , waits for the same query to get finished

Comment: I checked the session files saved on my server , and it seems that the session variable is locked for the entire time , which blocks all other requests . Is there any way to bypass this situation?

Answer (score 0):

don't execute the query on page request. Put an ajax call in your page and call another action that execute the query and return the result.